# System of linear equations: and a small perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If $Ax=b$ and $Ax'=b'$ where $x'$ and $b'$ are $x$ and $b$ with a small perturbation, the following inequality will always hold:

$ (\left\lVert x-x' \right\rVert/\left / \lVert x \right\rVert) \le \left\lVert A^{-1} \right\rVert \cdot \left\lVert A \right\rVert \cdot (\left\lVert b-b' \right\rVert / \left\lVert b \right\rVert) $.

My question is, when is this inequality an equality? (assuming $b \neq b'$)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have studied the proof but can't come up with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality comes from multiplying $\|x - x'\| = \|A^{-1} (b - b')\| \le \|A^{-1}\| \|b - b'\|$ and $\|b\| = \|A x\| \le \|A\| \|x\|$, and dividing the result by $\|x\| \|b\|$.  So you'll get equality whenever 
$\|x - x'\| = \|A^{-1}\| \|b - b'\|$ and $\|b\| = \|A \| \|x\|$.
Choose $x$ to maximize $\|A x\|/\|x\|$ with, say, $\|x\| = 1$, and $b = A x$.
Choose $y$ to maximize $\|A^{-1} y\|/\|y\|$ with, say, $\|y \| = \epsilon > 0$.
Take $b' = b + y$, $x' = x + A^{-1} y$.

Comment: Thank you! I am unsure of what it means "choose x to maximize"; can I see an explicit example?

Comment: "Choose $x$ to maximize ..." means find $x$ with $\|x\| = 1$ that gives the largest possible value of $\|Ax\|/\|x\|$.  You can do this (assuming we're using the Euclidean norm on vectors) by taking $x$ to be an eigenvector of $A^T A$ for its largest eigenvalue.  Similarly, $y$ will be an eigenvector of $(A^{-1})^T A^{-1}$ for its largest eigenvalue.